# Getting the line number of the Mono/Flux that returned Mono.empty()

Tags: java, project-reactor

Let's say I have a long chain of Monos. Some monos in the chain might return `Mono.empty()`.

I can recover with `switchIfEmpty`, but I'd like to know which mono raised the empty (maybe so I can know where to add smarter empty handling).

Is there a way to programmatically get this information?

Silly example. In cases where I return `how did I get here?`, how I can know if the first `flatMap` or the second `flatMap` triggered the empty handler?

```
        Mono.just("data")
                .flatMap(t -> {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }
                    return Mono.just("happy1");
                })
                .flatMap(t -> {
                    if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0) {
                        return Mono.empty();
                    }
                    return Mono.just("happy2");
                })
                .map(s -> {
                    return "successful complete: " + s;
                })
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
            return "how did I get here?";
        }))
        .block();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the dynamic nature of `Flux` and `Mono`, and to the fact that the `onComplete` signal is considered neutral enough that it is usually just passed through, there is no generic solution for this.

In your particular example, you could replace the `Mono.empty()` with something like `Mono.empty().doOnComplete(() -> /* log something */)`.
You could even directly perform the logging in the if block, but the decorated empty trick is probably adaptable to more situations.

Another possibility is to turn emptiness into an error, rather than a switch on onComplete signal.
Errors are less neutral, so there are ways to enrich them for debugging purposes. For instance, with a `.checkpoint("flatMapX")` statement after each flatMap, you'd get additional stacktrace parts that would point to the flatMap which failed due to emptyness.

A way of turning emptiness to error in `Mono` is `.single()`, which will enforce exactly one `onNext()` or propagate `onError(NoSuchElementException)`.

One thing to keep in mind with this trick is that the placement of `checkpoint` matters: it MUST be AFTER the `single()` so that the error raised from the single() gets detected and enriched.

So if I build on your snippet:

```
static final String PARSEABLE_MARKER = "PARSEABLE MARKER: <";
static final char MARKER_END = '>';

String parseLocation(Exception e) {
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
    e.printStackTrace(pw);

    String trace = sw.toString();
    int start = trace.indexOf(PARSEABLE_MARKER);
    if (start > 0) {
        trace = trace.substring(start + PARSEABLE_MARKER.length());
        trace = trace.substring(0, trace.indexOf(MARKER_END));
        return trace;
    }
    return "I don't know";
}

String testInner() {
    Random random = new Random();
    final boolean first = random.nextBoolean();

    return Mono.just("data")
            .flatMap(t -> {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0 && first) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
                return Mono.just("happy1");
            })
            .single()
            .checkpoint(PARSEABLE_MARKER + "the first flatMap" + MARKER_END)
            .flatMap(t -> {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() % 2 == 0 && !first) {
                    return Mono.empty();
                }
                return Mono.just("happy2");
            })
            .single()
            .checkpoint(PARSEABLE_MARKER + "the second flatMap" + MARKER_END)
            .map(s -> {
                return "successful complete: " + s;
            })
            .onErrorResume(NoSuchElementException.class, e ->
                    Mono.just("how did I get here? " + parseLocation(e)))
            .block();
}
```

This can be run in a loop in a test for instance:

```
    @Test
void test() {
    int successCount = 0;
    int firstCount = 0;
    int secondCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        String message = testInner();
        if (message.startsWith("how")) {
            if (message.contains("first")) {
                firstCount++;
            }
            else if (message.contains("second")) {
                secondCount++;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }
        else {
            successCount++;
        }
    }
    System.out.printf("Stats: %d successful, %d detected first, %d detected second", successCount, firstCount, secondCount);
}
```

Which prints something like:

```
Stats: 85 successful, 5 detected first, 10 detected second
```